# TCP port visible from inside nor outside

Tags: ip, tcp, port, socat

I've used autossh (reverse) connecting to my server. The ssh side works like used to. But in an ARM64 system, my Ubuntu has less possibilities but this is another story (...).
So what I see whit nmap the specific port with
127.0.0.1: they are open (and maybe listening)
but when I check the same with my intern IP: 192.168.1.11 then I see they are closed (ifconfig -a to double check my ip - yes).

I have no firewall running, no protection, (ufw also not working), blank iptables, but this makes no sense. Maybe something missing from install? I'm new to this kind of chipsets, so maybe the Ubuntu distro is inefficient and has less support for that.

What I would like to have: I would like also to see the port opened at 192.168...

Maybe there has to be a workaround? with ex. socat? I've tried but got:

```
socat[4525] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:12001}, 16): Address already in use
```

So if it is used, why I can't see it from outside (not only on the 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: *"I've used autossh (reverse) connecting to my server."* - and exactly how? I assume that you used the -R command for ssh to open the remote port, but did you give also a remote IP to use? Otherwise it likely is restricted to 127.0.0.1. And you also need to have `GatewayPorts yes` in sshd_config on your server.

Comment: Okay, maybe set the GatewayPorts, but this option is default commented out (from no), so I set manually and uncommeted it to yes
Regarding your question:
`/usr/bin/autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 20" -o "ConnectTimeOut 10" -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -NT -R42301:localhost:8081 myname@33.44.55.66 -p 123456 -i /home/...`
Where can I specify that on the remote host the remote host should use the external ip? Eg. 192.168.....? And further more, in older machines with common Ubuntu/Deb, I did not do such extra jobs to get it working (this is a new setup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> /usr/bin/autossh ... -R42301:localhost:8081 myname@33.44.55.66 ...
> ```

`-R42301:localhost:8081` - should be `-R*:42301:localhost:8081`. From [the openssh documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> **-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport**
> ...
>
> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server **will be bound to the
> loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a
> bind_address**. An empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’, indicates
> that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a
> remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts
> option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

Comment: Maybe this is also an answer, but without this, the GatewayPorts yes do the trick. However on my "old" server, this wasn't commented out, and worked also. So use that or use with a star should work. Thank you, so that's why I gonna accept this.